# Como copiar um repositório git local?

Tags: git

Já é de conhecimento comum que não é uma boa prática [copiar diretamente os arquivos físicos](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/61814) (mdf, etc) do banco de dados. Para tanto existem rotinas específicas que geram arquivos externos passíveis de importação.

Analogamente aos banco de dados, creio que também não seja correto copiar um diretório `.git`, ou mesmo o diretório inteiro do projeto, para cópia de segurança, ou para transportar em um pendrive e descarregar em casa.

**Sendo assim, qual o modo correto de copiar um repositório `git`?**

*É importante assumir aqui que trata-se de um repositório local, não hospedado remotamente em serviços como GitHub.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Existe um comando do git próprio para isso, chamado `git archive`.

É possível exportar o repositório para arquivo zip, por exemplo, com o seguinte comando:

```
git archive --format zip --output zipfile.zip master
```

Para mais detalhes, pode-se consultar a documentação via [`git help archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive).

Answer (score 1):

Não vejo por que não funcionaria copiar os arquivos, já que não haverá nenhum acesso concorrente (e maioria dos arquivos dentro do .git é imutável mesmo).

Mas se você quiser uma maneira alternativa, usando comandos do próprio git, pode fazer um simples **`git clone`** passando o caminho do seu repositório original

Assim você terá acesso a diversas opções do git clone que você possa achar úteis para a sua cópia (exemplos de algumas que achei interessantes: `--local`/`--no-local`, `--no-hardlinks`, `--bare`, `--depth`, `--single-branch`/`--no-single-branch`, `--recursive` etc. — consulte o manual do git para detalhes sobre cada uma)

Answer (score 0):

Um repositório Git é baseado em arquivos de código, ou quaisquer outro tipo, mais uma pasta oculta .git, como é um [DVCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control), cada repositório tem não só os dados (código) como as informações de histórico, é nessa pasta oculata que estão todas as informações sobre o repositório, histórico, branchs, tags, etc... Portanto, você pode movê-lo, copiá-lo sem perder informações. Mas deve fazer isso da pasta raiz.